# How to Modify MySQL Table Structures without Direct Access to the Database?

Tags: mysql

Good Morning,

I've been asked to make changes to a custom CMS, involving the addition and deletion of form fields and corresponding database fields.  The UI changes are pretty basic.  However, the twist is that I don't have direct access to the MySQL database.  I've only been given a .sql file.  I've edited it, changing the table structures to accomodate the UI modifications.  Besides the table edits in the .sql file, is there anything else I should do to it to ensure that it re-creates the database correctly?

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there anything else I should do to
>   it to ensure that it re-creates the
>   database correctly?

Can you request a *copy* of the database, or the database with dummy data, or even a script that creates the database? That way, you can take this home, and then double check your SQL file does the right thing.

Comment: When he says "I've only been given a .sql file" i think he means a script that creates the database.

Comment: Exactly.  It's just a script file.  I will create the DB locally using the .sql file.  Thanks for your suggestion:)